# Keras alternative to ImageDataGenerator for loading arbitrary numpy tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.x

The Keras's ImageDataGenerator looks great for simply progressively loading images and passing an iterator to the model.fit function. However, it seems to be only usable for images and for classification tasks.

I want to do regression, i.e., my labels are also arrays of the same shape as the training set ones. In practice, they are multidimensional (>1 channels) arrays like images but they are not images.

Any suggestions on what class to use to simply spit batches of data to a keras model.fit() for training a deep neural net?

The problem, of course, is that my datasets are much too large to fit in memory, which is why I need to use these generators/iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for your case is to use `tf.data.Dataset()`.

While it may take a relatively short time to accustom to it, it is the recommended way to load your data and use model.fit().

You can consult the documentation here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset

Is is new, fast, beautifully designed and easily extensible.

For instance, for your problem you may want to use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`; I will leave you discover its features :D.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at this.

Comment: You are welcome. I am sure it will satisfy your needs.

Comment: you know that calin (câlin) means hug in french

Comment: Nice, although I am Romanian and not French; in my language it does not mean anything; it is supposed to come from a medicinal plant :))

Comment: ahah cute :))))

Comment: and in fact at the moment, with my current generator, I have the message: WARNING:tensorflow:multiprocessing can interact badly with TensorFlow, causing nondeterministic deadlocks. For high performance data pipelines tf.data is recommended.

Comment: Like I said, tf.data.Dataset() is the way to go :D

Comment: So I guess tf.Data manages the multiprocessing (this is usually always a nightmare with mutex etc)

Comment: The thing is, I would like to use a dataset which I have in .h5 format (both input and targets are Nx128x128x2 tensors) but for the moment I find examples/tutorials where the have a list of individual files in a folder and they rather do image classification

Comment: thanks again, maybe you want to have a quick look at another question, which might be quite interesting because it's really a strange behavior of pyTorch w.r.t tensors and inverse Fourier transform : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61158860/why-is-pytorch-destroying-my-numpy-arrays

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to use Colab whose GPU instance has got 24 GB RAM to work with . You could also reduce your memory when you load the numpy array like the way I did [here](https://github.com/deepanshu-yadav/Gesture_Audio/blob/master/notebooks/train_jester_on_colab.ipynb)

Comment: haha thanks but I already have access to a server with 64GB RAM, I would rather need like 256 GB or 512GB